# tsc cannot find declaration files of express in apollo-server when using yarn workspaces

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg, apollo-server, yarn-workspaces, yarnpkg-v2

I am trying to build a monorepo with yarn workspaces (version 3.0.2), typescript(4.4.3) and apollo-server (3.3.0) in one of those packages. When running `yarn workspace graphql tsc --build` I get the following error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'express'. '...../.yarn/__virtual__/express-virtual-1169aebee1/0/cache/express-npm-4.17.1-6815ee6bf9-d964e9e17a.zip/node_modules/express/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  If the 'express' package actually exposes this module, consider sending a pull request to amend 'https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/express'

2 import express from 'express';
                      ~~~~~~~~~
```

I then tried to install `@types/express` but the error remains the same. How can I fix this issue?

My project structure looks like:

```
├── package.json
├── packages
│   └── graphql
│       ├── index.ts
│       ├── package.json
│       └── tsconfig.json
└── yarn.lock
```

The `index.ts` file I try to compile:

```js
import { gql } from 'apollo-server';

// A schema is a collection of type definitions (hence "typeDefs")
// that together define the "shape" of queries that are executed against
// your data.
const typeDefs = gql`
  # Comments in GraphQL strings (such as this one) start with the hash (#) symbol.

  # This "Book" type defines the queryable fields for every book in our data source.
  type Book {
    title: String
    author: String
  }

  # The "Query" type is special: it lists all of the available queries that
  # clients can execute, along with the return type for each. In this
  # case, the "books" query returns an array of zero or more Books (defined above).
  type Query {
    books: [Book]
  }
`;
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "skipLibCheck": false
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

My root `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "test-monorepo",
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.0.2",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ]
}
```

My `package.json` of graphql package:

```json
{
  "name": "graphql",
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.0.2",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^16.9.1",
    "apollo-server": "^3.3.0",
    "graphql": "^15.5.3",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `apollo-server` did not include `@types/express` as a `peerDependency`. The solution is to tell yarn that the package `apollo-server` needs `@types/express` in `.yarnrc.yaml`:

```yaml
packageExtensions:
  apollo-server@*:
    dependencies:
      "@types/express": "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `tsconfig.json` file, change `skipLibCheck` to `true`. This will skip type checking of declaration files.

Comment: But I don't want to skip type checking for all libraries just for this case. I would like to keep type-system accuracy.